# Have I misunderstood Tenacious?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

[My user stats show](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289396) 99 accepted answers and 22 of them have 0 upvotes (which makes > 20%)

**None of these are self-accepted** or CW.

Anyone know why I dont have the Tenacious badge yet?

Thanks

and I did email the team 4 days back, but no response there - hence the question here.

Comment: Sorry about not responding earlier, to Jeff credit he actually forwarded the email to me. So I take the blame ... sorry.

Comment: Man I want to upvote some of your recent answers ... but I also do not want to take your tenacious badge away.

Comment: You did not get the Tenacious badge yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran this on your user id on yesterdays data.

```
   select a.OwnerUserId as Id, 
    sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as [Non Zero Score Answers],  
    sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Zero Score Answers]
  from Posts q
  join Posts a on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId 
  where a.CommunityOwnedDate is null and a.OwnerUserId is not null
   and a.OwnerUserId <> isnull(q.OwnerUserId,-1)
   and a.CreationDate < getdate() - 10
   and a.OwnerUserId = 289396
  group by a.OwnerUserId
  having sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 5
```

It shows you have **17** accepted zero score answers and a total of 76 non zero score answers.

The calculation excludes all posts that are less than 10 days old, it is possible you will get tenacious in a few days.

My calculations show that you *may* get it in 4 days if nobody upvotes your accepted answers. This is a nasty hard badge to get when you have so many answers.

Comment: wow, thats much lesser than the stats on my own user page or the /reputation url, thanks for running this.

Comment: and by the way, 17/76 is 22% as well

Comment: @Jose its ... 17 / (17 + 76) :)

Comment: QUICK! EVERYONE GO UPVOTE THOSE ANSWERS!

Comment: @waffles: Indeed, duh!

Comment: @Mark:  Pah!  We'll just downvote'em back.

Comment: @Mark, you're _playing right into his hands!_

Comment: You think he cares more about rep than badges? Pah!