# Possibilities of getting Tenacious Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

I have Totally 21 accepted answers in that i have 8 accepted answers with zero vote in that two of my own question, I think, I am eligible for Tenacious Badge, but yet to awarded.

Comment: sorry I have only five question in that category

Comment: you got to wait for 5 days or so before the badge kicks in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66749/have-i-misunderstood-tenacious

Comment: is it possible for me get badge

Comment: if you're Tenacious enough ;)